# How to read tables from .dat file in C

Tags: c

I need to read a table from a .dat (ASCII) file that contains 3 columns with the number of rows being the first line in the .dat file and then store each column in separate array. I was advised to use fscanf but i dont know how!

```
//this is the .dat file (ASCII format)
inname.dat
```

```
//n -this is the first line in the .dat file and it represents number of rows in the table
2000
```

```
//these are the different columns, each of which should be stored in
//a separate  array x[n],y[n],y[n]
```

```
-0.9210340500E+01  -0.1642608881E+01   0.1000000000E+01
-0.9204236984E+01  -0.1645367146E+01   0.1000000000E+01
-0.9198134422E+01  -0.1648124933E+01   0.1000000000E+01
-0.9192030907E+01  -0.1650882006E+01   0.1000000000E+01
-0.9185928345E+01  -0.1653640866E+01   0.1000000000E+01
-0.9179824829E+01  -0.1656393051E+01   0.1000000000E+01
-0.9173722267E+01  -0.1659148812E+01   0.1000000000E+01
-0.9167618752E+01  -0.1661900759E+01   0.1000000000E+01
-0.9161516190E+01  -0.1664654970E+01   0.1000000000E+01
-0.9155412674E+01  -0.1667405009E+01   0.1000000000E+01
-0.9149310112E+01  -0.1670155764E+01   0.1000000000E+01
-0.9143207550E+01  -0.1672905326E+01   0.1000000000E+01
-0.9137104034E+01  -0.1675654054E+01   0.1000000000E+01
```

Answer (score 0):

If the advice is to use `fscanf` you can open the file and then use a loop such as

```
double varA, varB, varC;
while(fscanf(fil, "%lf%lf%lf", &varA, &varB, &varC) == 3) {
    // ...
}
```

Another way preferred by some is

```
char str[100];
double varA, varB, varC;
while(fgets(str, sizeof str, fil) != NULL) {
    if (sscanf(str, "%lf%lf%lf", &varA, &varB, &varC) != 3) {
        break;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: what about the first line where n is given? and don't i need some sort of a cycle to store each row of every column to an element of the array?

Comment: I am not providing complete code for you, but showing you how to read using `fscanf`. You can use a different loop to suit the task conditions.

Comment: thank you really but that is my main problem is that I don't seem to understand how to write a code for specifically this situation

Comment: I'm sorry, you must best consult a C tutorial course. That's not the aim of this site. You might benefit by reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: yeah sorry first timer here! I will check some tutorials and thanks for the help!